# how to set max_partitions_per_insert_block for clickhouse docker container

Tags: clickhouse

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187559/clickhouse-inserting-more-than-a-hundred-entries-per-query) but the link provided in the answer was broken. I've tried running the query `set max_partitions_per_insert_block=10000` using the web console but that didn't work. I've also tried

```
clickhouse-client --port 9000 -q "SET max_partitions_per_insert_block=10000"
```

which also didn't work. I'm running a docker clickhouse container. Any suggestions on how to set `max_partitions_per_insert_block`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I'm afraid to show you the answer because I don't want other people to read this and think that 10,000 is a good setting for `max_partitions_per_insert_block`. We recommend using a date for partitioning and typically by month - unless you have a lot of data and you partition by day. Partitioning by some other value is probably not a good idea because it leads to too many parts.

What is your scenario?

Here is how you define the setting in an `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SETTINGS max_partitions_per_insert_block = 10000
VALUES 
...
```

Comment: the max partition i need should be around 3000 and not 10000, but I wanted to be safe and set it to 10000. I have lots of data that are being streamed and there are around 3000 different stream objects.

Comment: Even 3000 is alittle high, but it will depend on the volume of data per partition. I've experienced issues with 5000.